# How to add/edit/manipulate data in my SQL Server database, if upload several tables to the datagrid the solution is implemented in WPF project in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

How to add, edit and delete (manipulate) data in my SQL Server database, working via `ObservableCollection`, if I upload several tables to the datagrid the solution is implemented in the WPF project in C#.

Faced with such a problem, when working with my WPF application in C#, I output data from my SQL Server database via an `ObservableCollection`, from several tables simultaneously into one datagrid, but I can't interact with the output data in any way. When I output data from one table, I can add new records, edit and delete existing ones.

```
public partial class МышьАдминистратор : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Автоматизированное_рабочее_место> ListАРМ;
    ObservableCollection<Мышь> ListМышь;
    public static учетEntities уч;

    public МышьАдминистратор()
    {
        уч = new учетEntities();
        InitializeComponent();
        ListАРМ = new ObservableCollection<Автоматизированное_рабочее_место>();
        ListМышь = new ObservableCollection<Мышь>();
        var queryАРМ = from a in уч.Автоматизированное_рабочее_место orderby a.Код_АРМ select new { a.Код_АРМ, a.Номер_кабинета, a.Инвентарный_номер_Блока, a.Инвентарный_номер_Монитора, a.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши, a.Инвентарный_номер_Клавиатура, a.Инвентарный_номер_МФУ };
       var queryМш = from e in уч.Мышь orderby e.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши select new { e.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши, e.Наименование, e.Тип, e.Код_Обслуживания };
        
        var queryОбсл = from h in уч.Обслуживание orderby h.Код_Обслуживания select new { h.Код_Обслуживания, h.Дата, h.Примечание, h.Стоимость };

        var querysumm = from e in уч.Мышь
                        join a in queryАРМ on e.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши equals a.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши
                        join g in queryКаб on a.Номер_кабинета equals g.Номер_кабинета                             
                        join h in queryОбсл on e.Код_Обслуживания equals h.Код_Обслуживания
                        select new
                        {
                            a.Код_АРМ,
                            e.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши,
                            e.Наименование,
                            e.Тип,
                            e.Код_Обслуживания,
                            g.Номер_кабинета,
                            g.Этаж,
                            h.Дата,
                            h.Примечание,
                            h.Стоимость
                        };
        
        gr.ItemsSource = querysumm.ToList();
    }

    private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Дата")
            (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
}
```

I tried to use editing methods as for one table:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int maxID = (from us in уч.Мышь select us.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши).Max();
    Мышь mouse = new Мышь();

    mouse.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши = maxID + 1;
    Enter(mouse.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши);
}

private void Enter(int IDMouse)
{
    Мышь mouse = new Мышь();
    mouse.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши = IDMouse;
    ListМышь.Add(mouse);
    уч.Мышь.Add(mouse);

    gr.ScrollIntoView(mouse);
    gr.SelectedIndex = gr.Items.Count - 1;
    gr.Focus();
    gr.IsReadOnly = false;
}

private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gr.IsReadOnly = false;

    if (gr.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var cell = gr.SelectedCells[0];
        gr.CurrentCell = cell;
    }
    else
    {
        gr.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo (gr.Items[0], gr.Columns[0]);
    }

    gr.BeginEdit();
}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Мышь mouse = gr.SelectedItem as Мышь;

        if (mouse != null)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Удалить Изделие под №" + mouse.Инвентарный_номер_Мыши + " с названием: " + mouse.Наименование, "Предупреждение!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                уч.Мышь.Remove(mouse);
                gr.SelectedIndex = gr.SelectedIndex == 0 ? 1 : gr.SelectedIndex - 1;
                ListМышь.Remove(mouse);
                уч.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите строку для удаления");
        }
}

private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    уч.SaveChanges();
    gr.IsReadOnly = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Данные были успешно сохранены");
}
```

UPD:
User Paul Maxwell gave me a useful recommendation, but I got the following error:

> On INotifyPropertyChanged and "Blocks" in OnPropertyChanged("Blocks") returns the error: Severity Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from "string" to System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"

Answer (score 0):

To add, edit, and delete data in a SQL Server database while working with an ObservableCollection in a WPF project you can follow these general steps:

- Create a model class for each table in the database that you want to work with. The model class should have properties that correspond to the columns in the table.
- Create a view model class that contains an ObservableCollection of the model classes. The view model should also have methods for adding, editing, and deleting records in the database.
- Bind the ObservableCollection to the DataGrid in your WPF view.
- Implement the add, edit, and delete functionality in the view model methods.

Example of how you can implement these steps:

Create a model class for each table in the database that you want to work with. For example, if you have a Customers table, you can create a Customer model class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Create a view model class that contains an ObservableCollection of the model classes. The view model should also have methods for adding, editing, and deleting records in the database. e.g.

```
public class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            _customers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
        }
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        // Add the customer to the database
        // Refresh the ObservableCollection
    }

    public void EditCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        // Update the customer in the database
        // Refresh the ObservableCollection
    }

    public void DeleteCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        // Delete the customer from the database
        // Refresh the ObservableCollection
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
}
```

Bind the ObservableCollection to the DataGrid in your WPF view. e.g.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

Implement the add, edit, and delete functionality in the view model methods. e.g.

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
        context.SaveChanges();
        Customers.Add(customer);
    }
}

public void EditCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var existingCustomer = context.Customers.Find(customer.Id);
        if (existingCustomer != null)
        {
            existingCustomer.Name = customer.Name;
            existingCustomer.Email = customer.Email;
            existingCustomer.Phone = customer.Phone;
            context.SaveChanges();
            Customers[Customers.IndexOf(customer)] = customer;
        }
    }
}

public void DeleteCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var existingCustomer = context.Customers.Find(customer.Id);
        if (existingCustomer != null)
        {
            context.Customers.Remove(existingCustomer);
            context.SaveChanges();
            Customers.Remove(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Using these methods you can use Entity Framework to add, edit, and delete records in the database. After making changes to the database, you can refresh the ObservableCollection to update the DataGrid in the view.

Comment: On INotifyPropertyChanged and "Blocks" in OnPropertyChanged("Blocks") returns the error: Severity Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from "string" to System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"
Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not a chance. That would require knowing a great deal more than a these tiny comments can contain. Somewhere in the models or combined view you have a data conversion issue. Consider asking another question.